# Creating a TouchItem in Vaadin displays too small on iphone4

Tags: vaadin

I am using Touchkit 1.0 for Vaadin but when I add TouchItems they display too small on both iphone 3 and 4. I have used the theme "touch", although whichever theme I put in "setTheme" seems to be ignored anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are using MobileApplicationServlet instead of ApplicationServlet?